# HTML 422 Error but AJAX form still submits correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

On my rails app I generated a custom form to create a Lesson object myself since form_for wasn't giving me the specifics I required. As a regular HTML form it submits without a hassle. As the app is booking lessons in a calendar the form is repeated for each hour in a week period, with a custom id for each.

I've then gone on to try and add some AJAX to the view so that the form submits without a whole page reload. On the surface it appears to work correctly as the Success function runs and the Lesson is created successfully. On my Chrome console though I get the following error repeated a number of times, and a similar error appears once on my rails server log:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/lessons 422 (Unprocessable Entity) 
 send 
 oe.extend.ajax
 (anonymous function) 
 oe.event.dispatch
 g.handle
```

If I try to create a lesson in a different time slot then the AJAX does not fire and the Lesson is created as normal with a page reload.

Other answers suggest that it's an authentication issue (especially since its a custom form I've made and not a form_for) but unlike their cases mine still seems to submit successfully the first time, though the AJAX does not work on the second attempt. I'm really unsure what is going on here so any guidance would be appreciated

```
#An except showing the custom form and JS to submit a new lesson
<form role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/lessons" class="new_lesson form-inline" id='newlesson-<%= @formatteddate.to_s%>' method="post">
        <button class="btn btn-default" name="commit" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-book no-slot"></i>
        </button> 
        <input class="form-control" name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">             
        <input class="form-control" id="lesson_starts_at_1i" name="lesson[starts_at(1i)]" type="hidden" value="<%=date.year%>"/>
        <input class="form-control"id="lesson_starts_at_2i" name="lesson[starts_at(2i)]" type="hidden" value="<%=date.month%>"/>
        <input class="form-control"id="lesson_starts_at_3i" name="lesson[starts_at(3i)]" type="hidden" value="<%=date.day%>"/>
        <input class="form-control"id="lesson_starts_at_4i" name="lesson[starts_at(4i)]" type="hidden" value="<%=@time.hour%>"/>
        <input class="form-control"id="lesson_starts_at_5i" name="lesson[starts_at(5i)]" type="hidden" value="00"/>
        <input class="form-control"id="lesson_teacher_id" name="lesson[teacher_id]" type="hidden" value="<%=current_user.id%>"/>
        <input class="form-control"id="lesson_confirmed_id" name="lesson[confirmed]" type="hidden" value="true"/>
      </form>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#newlesson-<%= @formatteddate.to_s%>').submit(function() {  
          var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
          var button = $(this).find('button');
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            data: valuesToSubmit,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(){
              button.html('<i class="fa fa-book free-slot"></i>');
            }
          });
          return false;
        });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems, but i solves it with this tag in the application layer, on the header section:

```
%html   
  %head
    ...
    = csrf_meta_tags
```

its HAML